# Two chrome launcher on dock - Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, launcher, 19.10

Is there an option to put two chrome launchers on side launcher with two different profiles. I've tried everything from [Can I put two chrome (different users) on my launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493142/) but somehow I always end up getting this:

[image]
(different profile but same icon)

Instead of this:

[image]

Comment: In the second screenshot, there are two different versions of Chrome, i.e. dev and stable.

Comment: Try changing WMClass as per the accepted answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/721041/different-launchers-for-firefox-versions

Comment: Tried. Same thing.